# Using underscore.js in Sublime 3

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, sublimetext3

I am getting an error while trying to use `underscore.js` within my `Node` project. I am using Sublime Text 3 as my IDE on a Windows 10 operating system. Here is my code:

```
var _ = require('underscore');
console.log(_.map([1, 2, 3], function(num){ return num * 3; }));
```

And here is the corresponding error message:

> module.js:471
>           throw err;
>           ^
>       Error: Cannot find module 'underscore'

I believe I've installed `underscore.js` correctly:

```
C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\underscore
```

and

```
C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Installed Packages\Underscorejs snippets.sublime-package
```

I'm not sure why it's not working, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I dont understand what a module not found error has to do with a text editor ?

Comment: sorry im new at this. does this mean i haven't installed underscore correctly?

Comment: yes, but it can mean a lot of things. What module bundler do you use ? Theres a lot of info missing here to help you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node package manager (**NPM**) installs packages *either globally or locally*. For local modules the default installation for these libraries is your: `<current_directory>/node_modules` directory. Since `underscore` is a local module if you don't see `underscore` within your `<current_directory>/node_modules` directory you'll need to *re-install this module* since something went wrong with your installation of `underscore`. Afterwards, you could try re-running your node program.

**TLDR**:

1. `npm i underscore`
2. Check that underscore is within your `<current_dir>/node_modules` directory
3. Re-run your node program.

**Note:** You should do this within a terminal window.

For reference checkout this [link](https://www.impressivewebs.com/npm-for-beginners-a-guide-for-front-end-developers/)

Hopefully that helps!